# center a fixed, table display div without setting a width

Tags: html, css

I have a div which displays messages, and I want it to appear fixed in the top center of the screen, the border should surround the text only (not the whole width of the screen) and the width is variable (depending on the string length of the message). is This possible? I have attempted many methods but with no success. Here is my latest [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rc9fa/363/). Thanks for reading.

```
div{
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. There are a few solutions possible, so let me walk you through them:

### CSS 2D transforms

I'd personally recommend this solution as it has the fewest caveats, and enjoys almost complete cross browser support (with respect to the browser share statistics we see today).

Remove the `right` property and set `left: 50%`. In order to compensate for the element's own width, we move it leftwards again by means of CSS 2D translation along the x-axis. This solution relies on [browser support for CSS 2D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), which is very wide spread — the only browsers that do not support this are Opera Mini and IE ≤8.

There are some properties that you don't actually need:

- `right: 0`
- `margin: auto`

p/s: Since you want it to be at the top of the page, I believe you have forgotten to add `top: 0` in your CSS.

```css
    div {
        text-align:center;
        position:fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 50%;
        border:1px solid grey;
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
        -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="center">variable string</div>
```

---

### Inline-block

If you *really* have to support IE ≤8, you will have to rely on using inline-block. I personally do not favour this solution as it adds unnecessary level of nesting to your markup, which is for stylistic purposes only.

```css
div.center {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
div.center > div {
  border:1px solid grey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="center"><div>variable string</div></div>
```

Comment: You can check browser support for CSS 2D transforms here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d. Will not work for IE version 8 and below.

Comment: intresting. I did a little bit on 2D transforms a while ago. I think I'll revisit it. Shame about old IE browsers. Thanks

Comment: You can always use the good old `inline-block` element fallback (see updated answer, second part), but make sure that are no whitespace (or at least no unescaped whitespace) between the elements, as they will be parsed as a whitespace as per inline element behavior.

Comment: probably best to use the the inline wrapped method to avoid the cross-browser testing head aches.I'll keep the the 2D code also. Great answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

No need for `display: table`. It works without it: http://jsfiddle.net/Rc9fa/366/ You should just wrap the text in a `span` for an inline element as I have done.